# Yii2 Yii::$app->request vs $this->request

Tags: php, yii2

Is there any reason why both methods `Yii::$app->request` and `$this->request` exist on a Controller? Is it just pure preference which to use? Both seem to resolve to the same object, so there really is no difference beside accessing it via a static object (`app`) or as a member of the current controller.

In the official guide (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests) they always use `Yii::$app->request`.

Also `$request` and `$response` on the Controller were added in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/18083 for unit test / mocking purpuse it seems.

Since `$this->request` seems supperior, shouldn't it be used everywhere instead of `Yii::$app->request`?

Comment: This seems an opinion based question. `$this->request` is only available in the controller, not even in the views, there you have to do `Yii::$app->controller` while `Yii::$app->request` is available everywhere. That seems reason enough to keep them both.

Comment: Why would you use `Yii::$app->request` in a view? this heavily violates the MVC and SOLID Principle. I understand the reason to keep it for backwards compatibility

Comment: Not sure about a view, but I use it in helper classes sometimes, I guess I should be passing the request from the controller when calling the helper method, but that couples the controller and the helper.

Comment: Actually, I just did a global search in a project and all the calls to `Yii::$app->request` are in controllers, most of them are the code generated by Gii on create and update methods. Not sure why Gii uses that instead of `$this->request`, now I am curious about this question as well.

Comment: You should always prefer `$this->request` in controller - it is more DI-way and removes one dependency on global service locator.

Comment: @RaulSauco Are you sure that last release of Gii generates code with `Yii::$app->request`? AFAIK it was changed at some point.

Comment: The gii template was updated in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/commit/ef0ea5fa8db7a77c7e801f637fb67cdfba479c45

Comment: @rob006 no, looking at the commit link that @Isitar sent, the update from `Yii::$app->request` to `$this->request` on the gii template rolled out on 2.2.2, ten days ago. I didn't know, I have `"minimum-stability": "stable"` on composer, I just did a `composer upgrade` and it still stays on gii version `2.1.4`.